# SlowCheetah transforms wrong element in my xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2012, slowcheetah

I have a `web.config` file, which I want to transform using SlowCheetah. The relevant fragment looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="ui/cms">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="AAA" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="WebServices">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="BBB" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I want to transform value `BBB` to `CCC`, so I wrote my `Web.CCC.config` transformation file:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <location path="WebServices">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="CCC" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, it results in `CCC` being inserted into `<location path="ui/cms">` instead of `<location path="WebServices">` - probably because it is the first one it locates in my `web.config` file.

How can I make SlowCheetah notice the different `path` parameter, and replace the correct node in my xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this can be obtained using `xdt:Locator` in a transformation file.

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <location path="WebServices" xdt:Locator="Match(path)>
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="CCC" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps anyone. [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) seems to work even with SO.